# Series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt {n^3 + 1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Alright, so I have a question regarding a series that I am attempting to solve:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3 + 1}}$$

To Start Off I attempted to use Direct Comparison Theorem:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt {n^3}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3 + 1}}$$

Then, It's clear that this series converges by p series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt {n^3}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$ 
But becuase this series is smaller, nothing can be assumed.

So then I moved onto Limit Comparison Theorem using:

$$b_n = \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$

But I got nowhere attempting to solve it:

$$\lim_{n->{\infty}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3 + 1}}*{\frac{n^{3/2}}{1}} = \lim_{n->{\infty}} \frac{\sqrt {n^3}}{\sqrt{n^3 + 1}}$$

Which, once using L'Hospital's rule kinda just alternates I guess.

So my question: How do I solve this/where did I make the mistake?

Note: Only learned divergence tests up to Limit Comparison Theorem.

*Only attempting to find if series is convergent or divergent*

Comment: You have $$0 < \dfrac{ 1 }{ \sqrt{n^3+1} } < \dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$ so why are you throwing out the Direct Comparison Test? That looks conclusive to me.

Comment: You have the answer!  By Direct comparison with $\sum 1/n^{3/2}$, the series you are asking about converges.  To be complete, you just need to specify that all terms are positive: $0<1/\sqrt{n^3+1}<1/n^{3/2}$.

Comment: But isn't that series smaller, not larger? I meant to put the < the other way, a mistake on my thoughts. So I just corrected it to what I think it was.

Comment: "but because this series is smaller..." How do you figure? You wrote in the line above it that the sequence was greater than what you started with!

Comment: $$0 = \sum_{n\ge 1}0 < \sum_{n\ge 1} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+1}} < \sum_{n\ge 1} \dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}} < \infty$$ Every term, you are adding a smaller positive value than another series you know converges. That tells you your "smaller" series converges.

Comment: Oh, I see what I did. It's bigger because the denominator of the other one is bigger, meaning the value when the fraction is accounted for is smaller. Lol thanks for pointing that out guys.

Comment: Yes, your first inequality is backwards, as others have said. Correct it, and then you know the sum exists. It's not clear of "solve" means find the value - I doubt you can get a closed form value for the sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $:$ Observe that $\frac {1} {\sqrt {n^3+1}} < \frac {1} {n^{\frac 3 2}}$ for all $n \geq 1$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {n^{\frac 3 2}} < \infty.$

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\dfrac1{\sqrt{n^3+1}}}{\dfrac1{n^{3/2}}}=1.$$

Answer (score 2):

A polynomial is *asymptotically equivalent* to its leading term, so $n^3+1\sim_\infty n^3$, whence

$$\frac1{\sqrt{n^3+1}}\sim_\infty\frac1{n^{3/2}},$$
and the latter is convergent.

Comment: Wow! Very elegant, sir! $(+1)$

Answer (score 1):

By the limit comparison test, you should have that $$a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+1}}\quad\text{and}\quad  b_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3}},$$

and now we take the limit of $a_n\div b_n$, as thusly demonstrated:

$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+1}}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3}}} \\ &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n^3}}{\sqrt{n^3+1}} \\ &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^3}}}.\end{align}$$

Since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}=0$, it follows that  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+0}}=\frac{1}{1+0} = 1 > 0$$ and by *that*, we can conclude that this limit exists, for which $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^3}}$ converges.

$$\therefore \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+1}}\;\text{also}\; \boxed{\text{converges!}}$$

Comment: Thanks, this explanation helps to explain how I didn't get the correct answer with the LCT!

Comment: @ChristianMartinez no problemo! This site encourages hints more, as opposed to just full answers, but meh, the limits look pretty so I just wrote the whole thing, basically, hahah ;)